# Bing Custom Search Instance showing results outside active domains (EDIT: Now giving no results for any queries)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing

Having a problem with Bing Custom Search.

I list only two entries in the Active tab:

https://www.ladottransit.com

https://store.ladottransit.com

Nothing listed under the "blocked" tab.

Run a search for "reports" and I get results from crimereportsforneighborhoods.brecordsbzc.com, which is clearly outside the parameters.

[image: UNLISTED RESULTS]

I also lost the ability to remove or edit active entries in a previous instance (I had to create a new instance to get them back). These icons ("controls") are no longer displayed in that instance.

[image: NO CONTROLS]

Thanks for your assistance.

EDIT: Here's screen cap of a search for "candy" (once I removed the errant Actives):

[image: Screen cap of search for Candy]

EDIT 2: I removed all pinned entries and the problem seemed to go away, and I launched. But I went to check this afternoon and I'm now I'm getting no results for any queries. The following was a search for Downtown (which should have numerous results).

[image]

This is the return I get regardless of the query. Code has not changed since testing and launch. Placed the JS snippet again and getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to repro the out of domain result issue. Below is the snapshot. For controls, they shifted to right and they are difficult to see as there is a gap in UX between ranking adjustment and controls. You can scroll towards right and they should be visible. If you can't see the scrollbar, pls change the browser and try. I tried in edge and it works.

[image]

Can't repro with "candy" query. It's weird that you are seeing and I can't repro. Just make sure that you don't have anything pinned - pinned results are not shown in "active" tab. Else, you need Cognitive Services support team to look into this matter.

[image]

Comment: Nice save on the missing controls! Sure enough, there they are. As far as the out of domain issue, you may be able to reproduce it if you do a search for something dumb (I just now searched for "candy" and got a couple weird results). Even a search for "search" returned the top three as out of domain.

Comment: Edited the question to include a cap of the weird results.

Comment: Edited previous answer with new comments.

Comment: The queries work on BCS Dashboard, but as of today, not working on the site.

Comment: I'm looking at Bing Webmaster Tools, and it looks like a recent crawl may have gone wrong somehow. Pages indexed went from 374% to  -2%. Trying to see what went wrong...

Comment: If you are getting results on customsearch.ai, you should get on site as well.

Comment: That's a good point. Using the JS snippet provided on "Consuming UI." This has worked beautifully up until now. The search bar renders correctly, but I'm just not getting any results.

Comment: In the midst of this, I still keep getting random results outside the domains on customsearch.ai. I'm going to try a brand new instance and see if that works.

Comment: I created a new instance, included the two sites I want searched, and tested with "downtown." Good results, nothing outside domains. I plugged in the subscription key and copied the JS script to an otherwise blank page. Launched. This returns "No results were found for your query."

Comment: Can you check in "API Endpoint" tab on customsearch.ai? If you see results on this page by clicking on "Test API", things are okay. The "Definition Editor" page doesn't include response for your subscription key and hence may be misleading.

Comment: Okay, I think you're onto something here. Getting the message: "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." As far as I'm aware, I've secured a valid subscription key, which I recorded in my records. And this key has worked up until very recently.

Comment: If this is a free access key, this might have expired. If this is a paid key, make sure it is for custom search and not for Bing Search APIs v7.

Comment: I just manually added a new subscription, and plugged in the new keys on the API endpoint tab, and this time got a response. So I plugged the same key into the Hosted UI tab and hit save. Looks like this did the trick. and so far no out-of-domain results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In spite of my having confirmed with MS billing department that I was in good standing on my subscription for launch, it indeed appears to have expired, and somehow not automatically renewed. I guess that was the free trial access key, despite my understanding on the phone. I think we're good for now. Appreciate the help on this, @Ronak.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. Maybe you want to accept the answer so that it is useful to other folks.

Comment: I'd like to, but the primary problem of out-of-domain results remains an issue.

Comment: From what I've gathered, turns out this was a bug of some sort, and it has been resolved by the engineers as of this morning. So far, I'm no longer getting out of domain results, so things are looking much better. Going to mark this as answered.